# I'm working on creating a static node.js server

Tags: node.js

I am working on creating a static node.js server that just serves up the plain html, css, and javascript that is in the specified directory. I am trying to get the server to read every subdirectory and route the url to the file it specifies. However it only reads the root directory.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var array = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
function getAllSub(array){
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i].indexOf(".") == (-1))
        {                     
            array = array.concat(array[i] + "/" + fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/" +     array[i]));
        }
    if (array[i].indexOf("/") != (-1)){
        var foldcon = array[i].substr(array[i].indexOf("/") + 1);
        var folder = array[i].substr(0, array[i].indexOf("/"));
        foldcon = foldcon.split(",");
        for (n = 0; n < foldcon.length; n++){
            foldcon[n] = folder + "/" + foldcon[n]
            if (foldcon[n].indexOf(".") == (-1)){ 
                console.log([foldcon[n]]);
                foldcon[n] = getAllSub([foldcon[n]]);          

            }
        }
        array.splice(i, 1, foldcon);

    }

}


return array;
}
array = getAllSub(array);
console.log(array);
```

Right now this code reads the directory and it recognizes if an item in the array of files is a folder, however it doesn't add the files from the subdirectories into the array properly. Right now it kinda goes all infinite recursion, and I can't really figure out how to stop it.
This isn't meant to be something I am actually going to use, I just thought it would be a good project to work on to introduce myself to the basics of node.js

edited^

Comment: That's not how things work here. You should re-accept my answer and start another question for this question

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late, but this is the right answer for a recursive solution to reading file paths in sub-folders:

```
var fs = require("fs");

/**
 * Recurse through a directory and populate an array with all the file paths beneath
 * @param {string} path         The path to start searching
 * @param {array} allFiles      Modified to contain all the file paths
 */
function readdirSyncRecursive(path, allFiles) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(path);
    if (stats.isFile()) {
        // base case
        allFiles.push(path);
    } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        // induction step
        fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(fileName) {
            readdirSyncRecursive(path + "/" + fileName, allFiles);
        });
    }
}

var allFiles = [];
readdirSyncRecursive("/path/to/search", allFiles);
console.info(allFiles);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var array = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i].indexOf(".") == (-1))
    {
        // you need to use the return value from concat
        array = array.concat(array[i] + "/" + fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/" + array[i]));
        console.log('if executed');
    }

}
console.log(array);
```